# Android deactivate "double tap to activate" but still describe reciclerview elements talk back

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile, talkback

I am working on an app on Kotlin, there is a list of elements on a recycler view, I want talk back not to say "double tap to activate" but keep describing the elements on my recycler view as the rows on the recycler view have no actual action.

Comment: check this for more info 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/basic-android-accessibility/